# C++ code in doom mode is shown as errors

Tags: doom, c++

I've C++ file written in style c++17 opened in doom emacs. Below is the contents of the file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int arr[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    float numbers [] = { 0.1f, 1.1f, 2.2f, 3.f , 4.f, 5.};
    int nums [10] {1};


    for(int i = 0; i< 10; ++i) {
        cout << nums[i] << endl;
    }

    struct Point
    {
        int x;
        int y;
    };

    struct Line  {
        Point p1; Point p2;
    };

    Line longLine {0, 0, 100, 100};
    Line anotherLine = {100};
    Line shortLine{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}};

    cout << anotherLine.p1.x << "\t" <<anotherLine.p1.y << "\t" << anotherLine.p2.x<< "\t" << anotherLine.p2.y << endl;
    cout << shortLine.p1.x << "\t" << shortLine.p1.y << "\t" << shortLine.p2.x << "\t" << shortLine.p2.y << endl;
}
```

Below is the screenshot of the emacs buffer -

[image: C++17 style error in doom emacs]

I think the false compilation errors shown are due to doomm emacs is not recognizing latest c++17 style.

Any idea how to update the C++ version in doom emacs so there is no false compilation error in the editor?

Note: I've asked the same question in discord as well https://discord.com/channels/406534637242810369/1033136372237729822

Comment: Emacs doesn’t generate any error messages; it relies on running external programs to check for errors. You need to figure out what system you are using for doing that (because of course there is more than one). Flymake? Flycheck? LSP? CEDET? Something else?

Comment: In doom-emacs i'm using this config `       (cc +lsp)         ; C > C++ == 1` in `~/.doom.d/init.el`. I don't know what else config I need to change.

Comment: I don’t use doom emacs, so I don’t know what that does. Presumably it means that you are using `lsp-mode`, which usually runs `clangd` for C++ code. You should read the documentation for `lsp-mode` and for `clangd`.